# Java code calling Lock.lock(), not Lock.interruptibly(), still gets interrupted

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, interrupt

I think Lock.lock() is not interruptible, while Lock lockInterruptibly() can be interrupted. So I tried:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Lock l = new ReentrantLock();
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                l.lock();
                System.out.println("Thread 3 start");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("lock is interrup")
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    l.unlock();
                }
                System.out.println("Thread 3 end");
            } // end run
        });
        t.start();

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        t.interrupt();
        t.join();
    }
```

On running it, it prints:

```
Thread 3 start
lock is interrupted
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at mygroup.UseLock$3.run(UseLock.java:42)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Thread 3 end
```

Well I expected that Thread 3 is not interruptible because there's `l.lock();`

So where did I get wrong? What's indeed an non-interruptible thread?

Appreciate your explanations!

Comment: It does not interrupt your `l.lock()` but your `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: The top of the stack trace is `at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)`. That means the exception is being thrown by the `Thread.sleep(5000)` call, not the `l.lock()` call.

Comment: Note that `Lock#lock()` not being interruptible only means a thread _blocked waiting to acquire the lock_ cannot be interrupted. But after acquiring the lock, the thread can perform interruptible actions (e.g., `Thread#sleep(long)`).

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, your test is flawed because the thread is not interrupted when `l.lock()` is called. In order to test this properly, you should additionally call `l.lock()` just before `t.start()`. This will cause the `l.lock()` call within thread `t` to block, and the interrupt will arrive while it is blocked, and since `l.lock()` does not allow interrupts, it should continue to block in spite of the interrupt. After sending the interrupt, your main thread can wait a second or two and then release the lock. In thread `t` You should then test to make sure that the thread has the interrupt status set immediately upon returning from `l.lock()`. Here is an example:

```java
Lock l = new ReentrantLock();
// test Lock.lock()
Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        l.lock();
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println("Lock.lock() was interrupted.");
    }
    if(Thread.interrupted()) {
        System.out.println("Thread was interrupted and Lock.lock() was not interrupted.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Thread was not interrupted");
    }
    l.unlock();
});

l.lock();
t.start();

Thread.sleep(1000);
t.interrupt();
Thread.sleep(1000);
l.unlock();
t.join();

// now test Lock.lockInterruptibly()
t = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        l.lockInterruptibly();
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println("Lock.lockInterruptibly() was interrupted.");
    }
    if(Thread.interrupted()) {
        System.out.println("Thread was interrupted and Lock.lockInterruptibly() was not interrupted.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Thread was not interrupted");
    }
    l.unlock();
});

l.lock();
t.start();

Thread.sleep(1000);
t.interrupt();
Thread.sleep(1000);
l.unlock();
t.join();
```

This should print:

```
Thread was interrupted and Lock.lock() was not interrupted.
Lock.lockInterruptibly() was interrupted.
```